# Interpolating on a 2D grid python

Tags: python, grid, 2d, interpolation

I'm having small troubles to understand how to implement a cubic interpolation on a grid. 
I have 25 magnitude values stored on a 1D array. Each values represents the number inside a cell. Thus, the values are being showed on a 5x5 imshow image where each of the 25 resulting cells represents my stored values.

I have successfully used built-in interpolation parameters on imshow but I would really like to return the result of the interpolation.

```
data = 1D numpy array with 25 values
imshow(data .reshape(5, 5), origin='upper', interpolation='lanczos', cmap=cm.jet)
```

I was trying to go with this built-in scipy interpolation function, however I do not know it it is really the best way.

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:4:100j, 0:4:200j]
grid_z2 = griddata(np.array([arange(5), arange(5)]).T, data, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

I'm receiving a ValueError with different number of values and points. If this is not really the best way I'm able to use other approaches.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file.py", line 100, in <module>
grid_z2 = griddata(np.array([arange(5), arange(5)]).T, data, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\ndgriddata.py", line 212, in griddata
rescale=rescale)
File "scipy\interpolate\interpnd.pyx", line 840, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.__init__ (scipy\interpolate\interpnd.c:9953)
File "scipy\interpolate\interpnd.pyx", line 78, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase.__init__ (scipy\interpolate\interpnd.c:2342)
File "scipy\interpolate\interpnd.pyx", line 121, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase._check_init_shape (scipy\interpolate\interpnd.c:3085)
ValueError: different number of values and points
```

Comment: please post full error traceback

Comment: @Julien Spronck Sorry about that, edited to reflected your request.

Comment: in the traceback, you see `square_mag[:, 2]` instead of `data` ... the error could come from there as `square_mag[:, 2]` is not a 5x5 array

Comment: @Julien I corrected my original post. square_mag[:,2] is the same as data. I changed the name for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I think I manage to use interpolate.RectBivariateSpline to satisfy my ends.
Here's the full complete code:

```
from scipy import interpolate

x = arange(5)
y = arange(5)
sp_x = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, data)

nx = linspace(0, 4, 50)
ny = linspace(0, 4, 50)
n_data = sp_x(nx, ny)
```